# AngularJS - $timeout is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I try to inject $timeout in the `run` function but I get that it is `not a function` when I try to call it. Why ?

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', ngCookies']);

mainApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout'
        function ($rootScope, $location, $route, authService, $timeout) {
...
}]);
```

Comment: there is lot of syntax error in this code. correct it and try again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
mainApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout'
        function ($rootScope, $location, $route, authService, $timeout) {
...
}]);
```

should be:

```
mainApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$route', 'authService', '$timeout',
        function ($rootScope, $location, $route, authService, $timeout) {
...
}]);
```

see 'The array annotation' part here:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#the-array-notation)

Answer (score 3):

When you annotate function with names of dependencies, the order of appearance should match.

```
...
mainApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$route', '$timeout', 'authService', 
        function ($rootScope, $location, $route, $timeout, authService) {
...
}]);
```