# Rare bug with TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, timeout

Im using a $timeout in my app to show a spinning spinner when a button is clicked. im doing that like this way -> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742247)

And I have it like this

```
vm.upShipment = function(){
    vm.test="true";


     vm.saveButtonText = "Saving";
     $timeout(function(){
        vm.test="false";
        vm.saveButtonText = "Save";
    },1000);
...
```

I tried to solve it by trying all in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272255/angularjs-timeout-is-not-a-function). The directives are injected correctly, But it keeps throwing me the same TypeError.

> TypeError: $timeout is not a function

Comment: Did you inject `$element` into your controller?

Comment: jsut try to add `console.log(typeof $timeout, $timeout);`  and see what is the case that $timeout is not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$timeout not defined error in AngularJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009370/timeout-not-defined-error-in-angularjs-app)

Comment: its not a duplicate, before make this question I search a lot in stackoverflow 
on similar question, I try everything to solve this issue, the directives are well injected. @alexmac, what can be the cause of this ? Why $element its necesary ?

Comment: can you share the whole directive?

Comment: My injections [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/Tz10OAnZYahMdico97J4/) @NarenMurali

Comment: @GaboRuiz This is a controller, give me the directive highlighting the $timeout error.

Comment: what directive? i mean by saying "directives" that I already injected the $timeout in the controller @NarenMurali

Comment: @GaboRuiz fine my mistake, so can you show the error happening in a JSfiddle to me?

Comment: provide the full controller code and directive code plz.

Comment: I put the part of the controller in the question. Im not using a external directive. The $timeout injection its okey.  @JesusCarrasco

Comment: are you sure you inject $timeout like needs in controller? thats why im asking for your code to see how are you injected. You know that kind of error always means injector failure.

Comment: Im sure, but i dont know, can you check it? I put only the controller declaration just to see if the $timeout injection its ok.. [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/Tz10OAnZYahMdico97J4/) @JesusCarrasco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$event` in the function but in [ ] you havent. thats why `$timeout` not working. inject `$event` inside the function.

If $event not exist try delete.

Comment: I already tried like that. In the same order outside the funcion and inside too. but shows this error -> [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24eventProvider%20%3C-%20%24event%2   @JesusCarrasco

Comment: maybe $event doesnt exist. try delete in both [ ] and function

Comment: or again in the plnkr if you share the full controller can make better answer.

Comment: Its solved, by removing the $event in both [] and function. Thanks

Comment: glad to help you.